# AI Stability for Blender "installed" correctly, but does not appear in Blender

Tags: add-on

After a reboot or two, AI Stability does not appear where Pixxo said it would. So, what's that deal?

Thanks for the help, everybody.

[image]

Comment: That appears to be a third-party addon. This Q&A site only helps with questions about problems using Blender itself and its built-in addons so your question is off-topic here. You should ask the author directly. Anyway you have an answer from your previous question about it yesterday.

Comment: Tremendous. Thanks.